# Are SQLite rowid assignment invariant after rollback?

Tags: sqlite

If I do a ROLLBACK in SQLite and then rerun the ROLLBACKed sequence, will rowid from INSERTs be generated the same?

Comment: Why does it matter? They're keys to rows in the b-tree that holds a table, that's all. What the numbers are shouldn't matter one bit.

Comment: @Shawn rowid after insert is the closest thing sqlite has to automatic name generation, similar to pointers returned from malloc.

Comment: And just like malloc, you don't care *what* the address/rowid is, just that you have it and can use it when needed.

Comment: @Shawn I think what you are missing is the context/scenario. I purposely omitted it because being *a lot* to explain and inevitably discuss, and the question is in itself pretty much answerable as is. If nobody answers this question within a day or two I'll rewrite it with full background and give you a heads up.